# PlatformActionList consuming API calls

Tags: rest-api, api, metadata-api

I'm having trouble dealing with my API calls limit. I found that the main object that is consuming this API calls is **PlatformActionList** (I'm not a developer, I'm not even sure if this is an object).

What is PlatformActionList? Where is it used in Service Cloud? Why could be consuming so many API calls?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are your users using SF mobile App?

Comment: Also worth looking into : https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/213576/what-user-actions-cause-an-api-call

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the link, I didn't found that one in my research. We actually don't have any users with mobile App...could it be custom buttons? Would you help me understand where can I find this custom buttons in order for me to understand if they are related to this issue?

Comment: Custom Button does consume API calls